# A way to center a span inside of div relatively to contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a fancy button.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgLZ8/4/)

```
<div class="button" data-button='closed'>
    <div class="button-default">
        <span class="button-text">Click</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="button-overflow">
        <span class="button-overflow-text">Confirm!</span> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The idea is that by default it displays 'Click' and when clicked it switches to 'Confirm'.

The problem is that I don't know how to make 'Click' and 'Confirm!' be always centered. I want it so no matter what text I put there - it still will be centered.

Comment: Look at the CSS `text-align` property

Comment: Do you want it centered horizontally and vertically?

Comment: look at this link -- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgLZ8/14/) -- due to position relative your confirm button is falling down

Comment: @Euphe my answer is updated to center the text vertically/horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

Just add

```
text-align: center;
```

to `.button`.

forked fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Wd5vP/

Comment: and for vertical-align add line-height:28px

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the CSS slightly, as such:

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #EEE;
    width: 100px;
    height: 28px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
body {

    font-family:Arial;
}


.button-text {
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
}
.button-overflow {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 28px;
    right: -100px;
}

.button-default, .button-overflow {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to your css class `.button`

It would look like this now:

```
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #EEE;
  width: 100px;
  height: 28px;
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
```

}

You also need to update your css class `.button-overflow-text` to `display: inline` and remove `text-align: left` and `vertical-align:middle`:

```
.button-overflow-text{
  display: inline;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just add text-align:center to .button-overflow

```
.button-overflow {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell; 
    background:green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 28px;
    right: -100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It's the same answer of @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This modified CSS worked for me:

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #EEE;
    width: 100px;
    height: 28px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;

}

.button-default{text-align:Center;}
body {

    font-family:Arial;
}


.button-text {
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
}
.button-overflow {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell; 
    background:green;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 28px;
    right: -100px;
}
.button-overflow-text{
    text-align:Center;

}
```